# Relational Databases

Tags: relational-database, object-oriented-database

I understand that Relational Databases are fairly new, and I agree that Object Oriented databases are starting to gain popularity. Do you believe that Object Oriented databases will someday replace Relation Databases? Or is there a new technology out there that is better in terms of efficiency and ease of use than Relational Databases?

Comment: Since when is a computing tech from the '70s fairly new?

Answer (score 2):

It is often said that relational databases roots in set theory and logic. Let me expand this simplistic observation a little. In second half of 19th century inspired by George Boole algebra De Morgan, Pierce, and Schröder developed algebra of binary relations. In 20th century the subject matured with influence by Tarski, who is considered one of the greatest logicians. Tarski carried on generalizing binary relations and inventing cylindric algebras. It would be natural to expect that his invention would find practical application in information handling field (databases) -- and this is remarkably *not the case*. Ask your fellow programmers how many of them heard of [RelView](http://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~progsys/relview/). On the other hand, widely recognized Codd's relational algebra is entirely different from either algebras of binary relations or cylindric algebras.

To summarize, skepticism of any "latest-and-greatest" innovation in database field is healthy: any new entrant has to prove **a lot** in order to earn recognition.